# e^x derivative using first principles

Tags: calculus

Using the Taylor series expansion for e^x , show that the
derivative of e^x (using first principles) is ex (include at least three terms of the series to confirm the derivative of e^x)

Comment: ...but Taylor series **use** derivatives, so isn't that going to be pretty circular? Besides, and as far as I know, that is not "first principles" ...

Comment: No, you do it.$\phantom{}$

Comment: Do you have a question about this exercise?

Comment: @anomaly No, I do it. You know that $e^x=1+x+x^2/2+o(x^2)$. Therefore,  $(e^x)'=\lim_{h\to 0}(e^{x+h}-e^x)h=\lim_{h\to 0}e^x(e^h-1)/h=\lim_{h\to 0}e^x(1+h/2+o(h^2)/h)= e^x$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$$

thus

$$(e^x)’=0+1+2\frac{x}{2}+3\frac{x^3}{3!}+...=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...=e^x$$